# Efficient way to check if unicode is a digit or a decimal in Python

Tags: python, unicode

What is the most efficient way to check if unicode is a digit or a decimal, I know I can do various if  statements like:

```
 if unicode.isdigit(self.initial_bet.text) and  unicode.isdigit(self.initial_odds.text)...
```

The unicode can be both, two of type decimal, two of type digit or combination of either, is there a better way to check other than many if statements?

Pseudocoe:

if a is a digit and b is a digit:
    return func

elif a is a decimal and b is a decimal:
    return func

elif a is a digit and b is a decimal:
    return func

and so on ....

else
    do something else

Comment: Please provide the full set of if statements you had considered. Also note that if `self.initial_bet.text` is already a unicode string, you can just do `self.initial_bet.text.isdigit()`

Comment: @krait added pseudocode

Comment: Do you want only 2 values or could be more?

Comment: @FlavioGarcia, there will only be two values

Comment: Is func a variable, or does each branch return a distinct value? If distinct values, are those constructed based on the nature of a and b, or are they hardcoded values that cannot change. These points are important for determining what the cleanest approach would be.

Comment: @krait if both conditions are true then, the self.initial_odds.text and self.initial_bet.text are passed to another function that returns a list of lists, I take data from that and create Button widgets using kivy

Answer (score 4):

If all inputs need to be either a decimal or a digit, then the following will work:

```
conds = [unicode.isdigit, unicode.isdecimal]
check = lambda v: any(f(v) for f in conds)

vals = [self.initial_bet.text, self.initial_odds.text]

if all(map(check, vals)):
    return func
# do something else
```

This will work for any number of inputs and any number of conditions, such that each input must satisfy at least one condition.

Also, it seems that unicode.isdigit is a superset of the functionality of unicode.isdecimal, thus any decimal should be a digit -- most of the difference lies in various unicode scripts, but with the ASCII range, the functions should have identical behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what your doing, but have you tried using isinstance(value, type).

```
if isinstance(a, int) and isinstance(b, float):
    return foo




res = [i for i in map(lambda x: isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float),[.5, 'a', 3, 4, 5])]
```

Comment: as in pseudocode a or b can be any combination of decimal or int so using isinstance would still require multiple if elif statements